# How many different pentagons in this grid?

Tags: geometry, combinatorics

The 3x3 grid is given as below;

[image]

> How many pentagons could be drawn by connecting the dots by lines in the grid?

**Rules:**

- Pentagons could be convex or concave.
- The lines cannot intersect each other.
- If reflecting or rotating a pentagon forms the same pentagon you have
  already counted before, it should not be added.

Example:

[image]

**Note:** The other question referred as the duplicate question's answers are not right. and the OP is missing. That's why I believe this question should be solved here and accepted.

Comment: The mathematician in me is begging to do this question. I shall oblige. :)

Comment: This is a subset of an already answered puzzle.

Comment: @IanMacDonald yes it is the same question, though it is more general, I missed it sorry, though there is no right answer in that question for the pentagon as far as I see. Someone might want to give the right answer here?

Comment: @IanMacDonald and it seems that --moti-- guy who asked the previous one is not active at all to accept an answer. If you want me to remove this that's fine though.

Comment: Trenin's answer has "Pentagons: 26". Are you saying this number is incorrect?

Comment: @IanMacDonald yes there is not that many pentagons available for sure.

Comment: While it certainly is a duplicate, I think the posted question is much clearer and more appealing as a "puzzle" than the older post. I would vote against closing it. (And I very much like the nice answer post :c) )

Comment: If the older question's answers are wrong, you can always post a better one yourself. That doesn't make this question any less a duplicate.

Comment: @randal'thor I did not see that question before posting this to be honest, then realized that the other question's OP was missing, and noone would able to accept that answer and there were no right one. Since this was a part of that question, I wanted to stay here. If this somehow disturbs the community, I can remove it.

Comment: No worries, there's nothing wrong with posting a duplicate - this doesn't deserve to get downvoted or deleted or anything. It *is* a duplicate though :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I get 23 pentagons. There are 126 ways of choosing 5 out of the 9 dots. After reducing for symmetry, only 23 are left, which you can check using Burnside's lemma. I drew these in the picture below. For any of these you can put a convex hull around the points. If that is a pentagon, then that is the unique one you can make from those points. If all the points are on the hull but it is a quadrilateral or triangle, then no pentagons are possible. If it has an interior point, then you have a choice of which side of the convex hull to replace by two sides connecting to the interior point.
>
> [image]

Comment: unfortunately, one of them is missing.

Comment: @Oray: You're right. I dismissed the case with a three points in a straight line on the convex hull but which also had an interior point. I overlooked that the interior point can be used to break up the straight line. Fixed it now.

Comment: Follow-up question: [how did you get 23 using Burnside's lemma?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/54433/5373)